# R: How to order a data frame by month

Tags: r

I've this data frame:

```
    year    Mes        Sesiones
1   2014    Abril       25721
2   2014    Agosto      14851
3   2014    Diciembre   71359
4   2014    Enero       2244
5   2014    Febrero     3149
6   2014    Julio       11540
7   2014    Junio       18648
8   2014    Marzo       10738
9   2014    Mayo        19151
10  2014    Noviembre   149655
11  2014    Octubre     42032
12  2014    Setiembre   33667
13  2015    Enero       41885
14  2015    Febrero     81120
```

I've applied this to make the colum "Mes" (that originally was a character column), a factor column (With ordered levels):

```
IkasaVisitas_Meses_Meses$Mes <- factor(IkasaVisitas_Meses_Meses$Mes,
                                       levels = c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril",
                                                  "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto",
                                                  "Setiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", 
                                                  "Diciembre"),
                                       ordered=TRUE)
```

But i still can get the months ordered as it should be: "Enero", "Febrero" ... "Diciembre". I know this is an easy taks, so if you could point me to a good reference would be glad.

To make this data frame i used this code (using dplyr):
I meantion this cause, "group_by" has caused me some problems in other situations:

```
IkasaVisitas_Meses_Meses <- IkasaVisitas_Meses  %>%
                          group_by(year,Mes) %>%
                          summarise (Sesiones = sum(Sesiones))
```

Comment: Going to factor for months is a good idea. You should be able to add to your chain `%>% arrange(Mes)` to order the rows. If you don't want them ordered within-group, add `%>% ungroup() %>% arrange(Mes)`.

Comment: @Thank you, just to mention that `%>% arrange (Mes)` only works if you've already converted the column to factor... Just saying for other people out there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, from your comment it sounds like it worked, here's the full answer:

Changing to a factor is a good idea (it doesn't have to be an ordered factor, that's more of a modeling convention).

Use `arrange` to order rows, use `ungroup()` to remove a grouping:

```
IkasaVisitas_Meses_Meses <- IkasaVisitas_Meses  %>%
  group_by(year,Mes) %>%
  summarise (Sesiones = sum(Sesiones)) %>%
  mutate(Mes = factor(Mes,
                      levels = c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril",
                                 "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto",
                                 "Setiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", 
                                 "Diciembre")) %>%
  # if you don't want the re-rordering to be within-group
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Mes)
```